# How to have multiple locations in hive to create external table?

Tags: sql, hive, location, external

I would like to create an external table with multiple locations in Hive. It means that I have a file A in a folder and another file B in another folder. What I want is create an external table in mixing the file A and B. The columns of A and B are the same.

Example:

```
     CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1(
     ...)
     LOCATION
     'hdfs/data/A', 'hdfs/data/B'
```

Comment: That's not possible.  An external table can only have a single location.  The only exception is partitions, but that's still not really different directories.

Comment: Too bad, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really finish my comment yesterday.  You can easily merge both files in a managed table.

Comment: What do you mean ?